# R 'fdrtool' package: how to use t statistic

Tags: r, fdr

Can one use t statistics from a Student's t-test directly in the `fdrtool()` function of `fdrtool` package (ver. 1.2.12)? [The paper](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/9/303/) (Strimmer-K BMC Bioinfo. 2008, 9:303) mentions this but as far as I can see the parameters only recognize "normal", "correlation" and "pvalue". Is there a workaround for a non-statistician ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a typo.

I took a look at the source for the `fdrtool` function and found that the `statistic` argument first gets passed through `match.arg` and then to `fdrtool:::get.nullmodel`.

Then, lo and behold:

```
args(fdrtool:::get.nullmodel)
# function (statistic = c("normal", "correlation", "pvalue", "studentt")) 
# NULL
```

and indeed there is a fully-implemented case in that function for the student t:

```
if (statistic == "studentt") {
    f0 = function(x, param, log = FALSE) {
        return(dt(x, df = param, log = log))
    }
    F0 = function(x, param) {
        return(pt(x, df = param))
    }
    iqr = function(param) {
        return(qt(0.75, df = param) - qt(0.25, df = param))
    }
    get.support = function() return(c(1, 1000))
}
```

Now, before I tell you how to access this option, I want to warn you that it's very possible it was disabled on purpose. I can't imagine why, because at first glance it seems like it should work fine. **But if you're planning to use this in a research result you ought to document the fact that this was essentially a "hidden" option and that you had to do some hacking to access it**. Moreover, I haven't actually tested this on my computer, so beware of typos.

Now, as for that hacking, the easiest way to get this to work would be to first simply type `fdrtool` into the R console. Then, copy and paste the output to a new R script (or use `sink` if you're fancy like that). The first few lines should look like:

```
function (x, statistic = c("normal", "correlation", "pvalue"), 
    plot = TRUE, color.figure = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, cutoff.method = c("fndr", 
        "pct0", "locfdr"), pct0 = 0.75) 
{
    statistic = match.arg(statistic)
...
```

Then all you have to do is change `c("normal", "correlation", "pvalue")` to `c("normal", "correlation", "pvalue", "studentt")`. That is, the first few lines should now look like

```
function (x, statistic = c("normal", "correlation", "pvalue", "studentt"), 
    plot = TRUE, color.figure = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, cutoff.method = c("fndr", 
        "pct0", "locfdr"), pct0 = 0.75) 
{
    statistic = match.arg(statistic)
...
```

Finally, reassign this function to `fdrtool` (don't worry, this won't break the underlying package, it will just act like a "mask" until you remove it with `rm`):

```
fdrtool <- function (x, statistic = c("normal", "correlation", "pvalue", "studentt"), 
    plot = TRUE, color.figure = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, cutoff.method = c("fndr", 
        "pct0", "locfdr"), pct0 = 0.75) 
{
    statistic = match.arg(statistic)
...
```

And run the whole thing or source the script. Then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that the maintainer of the package, Korbinian Strimmer, disabled the t-score based function on purpose. The reason for that is that it has been used incorrectly too often.

Prof. Strimmer is a nice guy and responded to my help request quickly and very comprehensively. This is what he suggests: T-scores in practice often do not follow a t-distribution but show rather an over- or underdispersion, which is why you should better use the **normal** option.

Before that, however, you will have to center your data

```
z.centered = z-median(z)
fdrtool(z.centered, statistic="normal")
```